# Windows authentication still bringing up login form

Tags: c#, windows, silverlight, authentication

I am working with a Silverlight business application, that I am using in IIS.

I have disabled all types of authentication apart from `Windows Authentication`.

In the web.config file the authentication is set as -

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
        <forms name=".FrontEnd_ASPXAUTH" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

And also, in the App.xaml.cs I have set -

```
WebContext webContext = new WebContext();

webContext.Authentication = new WindowsAuthentication();
this.ApplicationLifetimeObjects.Add(webContext);
```

I thought that this meant that because Windows Authentication is set, this means that the app is authenticating against my Windows user account on my machine.

However when I start up the application, it still brings up a login form, is there a way that I can load up the application, based on the windows login without a login form?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Not all browsers will be able to automatically send your windows credentials.

Comment: Good question, I tried it in both Chrome and IE.